# What's the difference between 'developmentAppKey' and 'productionAppKey' in the airshipconfig?

Tags: urbanairship.com

I couldn't find a real explanation of the difference between the `developmentAppKey(secret)` and the `productionAppKey(secret)`.

I've looked at stuff like: https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/1138363-configuring-your-airshipconfig-plist-for-multiple-targets, but couldn't get through the help there. What is the difference between the `developmentAppKey(secret)` and the `productionAppKey(secret)`?

From what I understand; the `developmentAppKey` will be used if `inProduction` is set to `false`. Whereas the `productionAppKey` will be used if `inProduction` is `true`. Is this correct? And if this is correct, consider the following example:

Two apps, **A-Debug** and **B-Release**, both exist in Urban airship. If I create the following `airshipconfig` (for the sake of explaining I've left out all unnecessary info):

---

developmentAppKey = **App-A-KEY**

productionAppKey = **App-B-KEY**

gcmSender = **1234567891**

inProduction = **false**

---

Is it possible to switch between the two apps using the `inProduction` flag? Or is this impossible due to the difference in *Google Project Numbers (`gcmSender`)* for the two apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Development app key/secret are for development environments (connecting to development servers).

Production app key/secret are for production environments (connecting to production servers).

DO NOT SWITCH BETWEEN THE TWO IN THE APP!!

I recommend creating two apps in Urban Airship (as you mentioned with A-Debug and B-Release). One for development, and another for production. From there, use the inProduction = false for developing and inProduction = true for when you publish the app. EG:

developmentAppKey = A-Debug-KEY
developmentAppSecret = A-Debug-SECRET

productionAppKey = B-Release-KEY
productionAppSecret = B-Release-SECRET

gcmSender = 1234567891

inProduction = false will use A-Debug Key and Secret
inProduction = true will use A-Release Key and Secret

This will help with testing your push notifications before sending them out to your entire audience.